# How do I correctly have multiple files use the same declarative_base()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here's what my file layout looks like:

```
.
├── main.py
└── models
    ├── base.py
    ├── building.py
    └── user.py
```

In base.py, all I have is a common declarative_base() to be used by all other classes.

**base.py:**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

In the other model files, I have some simple classes to model data.

**building.py:**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from base import Base

class Building(Base):
    __tablename__ = "building"

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    address = Column('address', String(50), unique=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Imports successful on building.py")
```

**user.py:**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from base import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = Column('username', String(50), unique=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Imports successful on user.py")
```

My main.py simply tries to import the data model classes.

**main.py:**

```
from models.user import User
from models.building import Building

print("Imports successful on main.py")
```

I can run `building.py` and `user.py` without issues, but if I run `main.py` I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models.user import User
  File "/[path to root director]/models/user.py", line 2, in <module>
    from base import Base
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

I want to be able to split my data model classes across multiple files to make the project more organized and easier to maintain. However, it seems like they all have to use the same `declarative_base` for things like `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` to work. I'd also like to keep the files where the classes are declared separate from the files where they're used.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried relative imports, i.e. `from .base import Base`? You may also have to add an `__init__.py` file to indicate that model is a python package.

Comment: If I use `from .base import Base`, then running `main.py` works but `user.py` gives an error when I try to run it directly: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`